# Is GlobalConfiguration in System.Web.Http.WebHost compatible with Owin?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I'm currently moving a WebApi 1 to a WebApi 2 project with OWIN.

In this piece of code GlobalConfiguration is in System.Web.Http.WebHost.

```
public class HandlerErrorFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var logFactory = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver
                            .GetService(typeof(ILoggerFactory)) as ILoggerFactory;
        ...
    }
}
```

I think this is not Owin compatible, but I can't find how to rewrite this so I can access the dependency resolver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not entirely clear about your question here...but GlobalConfiguration is comaptible with Owin middleware...There is also something called `System.Web.Http.Owin` which is an Web API Owin Adpater middleware...if you use this adapter then GlobalConfiguration must not be used...actually this is the same adapter which is used in case of Owin Selfhost scenario too...

if you are NOT using this adapter and just using other Owin middleware along with `System.Web.Http.WebHost`, then your above code should work just fine...are you seeing anything different?

Comment: I'm using the System.Web.Http.Owin in the new WebApi project, so GlobalConfiguration is to avoid! Does this middleware have something equivalent?

Comment: I have the same issue too. Is there an equivalent for owin? Did you find out?